# JBPM - No SQL Integration

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, jboss, jbpm

Can JBPM integrate with no-sql databases such as mongodb as its core db to store process states etc? Or does JBPM integrate better with relation databases such as MySQL as it seems to be using hibernate as ORM tool?

Comment: JBPM makes use of Hibernate ORM for persistence services. Since Hibernate ORM is an object-relational mapper it is not possible to use a non-relational database  without adapting the persistence layer.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoSierra

Answer (score 0):

JBPM 7.x has some development to provision different type of data stores.
But this is just an experiments so far.

In versions prior to 7 it was though rather tight integration which resulted in dependencies to JPA being still needed. With version 7 persistence layer was refactored and enabled much cleaner integration with different (than default) persistence store.

[Go here for more details](http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2017/08/nosql-enters-jbpm-as-experiment-so-far.html)